# text/hint in XML changed back from @string to hardcode

Tags: android, xml, string

After some time my xml files declaration are changing. sometimes when I open it my textvalues are changing from my @string values to regular texts. In this case:
`android:id="MAC Adress"` Can someone explain why?

```
 <EditText
       android:layout_width="330dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="@string/mac"      <!-- <-- THIS -->
       android:id="@+id/editText_mac"
       android:maxLength="17"
       android:paddingLeft="15dp"
       android:paddingRight="15dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a nice feature of `AndroidStudio`. It shows the content pointed by the id. But you are still using the reference to the localized value. As matter of fact, if you click on the text, you will see again   `@string/` instead of the value pointed by it

Answer (score 1):

try clicking on it, you'll see the previous string path. It just hides to make it clear and easy to access the string , instead of the path to string. It's the same with every one...